# John has to make 10 of the same cocktails in 10 different glasses. In how many ways John can pour this liquid into the glasses with restrictions.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> John has to make 10 of the same cocktails in 10 different glasses .
>   Each cocktail consisting of blue liquid at the bottom and red liquid
>   on top . In how many ways John can pour this liquid into the glasses
>   when we know that in every glass, red liquid must not pour before the
>   blue liquid ?

This is some of my atempts. Thank you.
 [image: This is some of my atempts]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

John must pour the blue liquid $10$ times and the red liquid $10$ times.  There are $20!$ orders in which the liquids could be poured.  However, by symmetry, for each of the ten glasses, it is equally likely that the red liquid is poured into the glass before the blue liquid as it is that the blue liquid is poured into the glass before the red liquid.  Thus, the number of permissible orders of filling the cocktails is
$$\frac{20!}{2^{10}}$$

Comment: Thank you for answer kind sir. But it confuses me why is there 20! orders, but not 10!? Can you please elaborate. Thank you.

Comment: The blue liquids must be poured $10$ times and the red liquids must be poured $10$ times.  This yields a total of $20$ times that liquid is poured, which is it would be possible (if impractical) to pour the liquids in $(10 + 10)! = 20!$ orders if there were no restrictions on the order in which each of the ten glasses were filled.